# Object object = *this seg fault (C++)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

I'm having a segmentation fault on the following piece of code:

```
main.cpp

List list;
Movie *m = new Movie();
list+m; //For testing the operator +
```

EDIT: Full List.cpp with all functions

```
#include "List.h"


using namespace std;



List::List() : head(0),tail(0),size(0) { }

List::~List() 
{
Node *current = head;
while( current != 0 ) {
    Node* next = current->getNext();
    delete current;
    current = next;
}

head = 0;
}

void List::addMovie(Movie *movie)
{
Node *curNode = new Node(movie);

if(head == NULL)
{
    head = curNode;
    tail = curNode;
    curNode->setNext(NULL);
    curNode->setPrevious(NULL);

}

else
{
    curNode->setNext(NULL);
    tail->setNext(curNode);
    curNode->setPrevious(tail);
    tail = curNode;
}

size++;

} 

Node *List::first()
{
return head;
}

Node *List::last()
{
return tail;
}

void List::addMovie(List & list)
{

Node *curNode = list.first();

while(curNode)
{
    addMovie(curNode->getContent());
    curNode = curNode->getNext();
}

}

void List::removeMovie(Movie *movie)
{
if(size == 0) return;
bool found = false;

Node *curNode = head;

while(curNode)
{
    if(curNode->getContent()->getTitle().compare(movie->getTitle()) == 0)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }

    curNode = curNode->getNext();
}

if(!found) return;

if(curNode == head && curNode == tail)
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    delete curNode;
    return;
}

if(curNode == head && curNode != tail)
{
    head = curNode->getNext();
    curNode->getNext()->setPrevious(NULL);
    delete curNode;
    return;
}

if(curNode != head && curNode == tail)
{
    tail = curNode->getPrevious();
    curNode->getPrevious()->setNext(NULL);
    delete curNode;
    return;
}

if(curNode != head && curNode != tail)
{
    curNode->getPrevious()->setNext(curNode->getNext());
    curNode->getNext()->setPrevious(curNode->getPrevious());
    delete curNode;
    return;
}


size--;

}
void List::removeMovie(List &list)
{
Node *curNode = list.first();

while(curNode)
{
    removeMovie(curNode->getContent());
    curNode = curNode->getNext();
}
}
int List::getSize()
{
return size;
} 


Movie *List::findMovie(string title)
{
Node *curNode = head;

while(curNode)
{
    if(title.compare(curNode->getContent()->getTitle()) == 0) return curNode->getContent();
    curNode = curNode->getNext();
}

return NULL;
}
void List::clean()
{

head = tail = NULL;
size = 0;
}

void List::operator =(const List& list)
{

head = list.head;
tail = list.tail;
size = list.size;

}

void List::operator +=(Movie *movie)
{
addMovie(movie);
}

void List::operator +=(const List& list)
{
Node *curNode = list.head;

while(curNode)
{
    addMovie(curNode->getContent());
    curNode = curNode->getNext();
}
}

List List::operator +(Movie *m)
{
 cout << "ok" << endl;
    List list = *this;
     cout << "ok" << endl;
    //list += m;
    //Node *f = list.first();
    /*while(f)
    {
        cout << f->getContent()->getTitle() << endl;
        f = f->getNext();
    }*/

    //return list;
    //Crashing after this
}

List List::operator +(const List& list)
{
 List tmp = *this;
 tmp.size++;

 return tmp;
}
```

I get a seg fault after doing list+m, getting this while debugging:
    No source available for "libstdc++-6!_ZNKSs7_M_dataEv() at 0x6fc5e26c"

Comment: Just edited the post with the operator

Comment: Run it under a debugger, get the exact point where the fault happens. `cout` is buffered, some output might never make it.

Comment: Is there a destructor for List?

Comment: Yes, and it was all working before I added the operators

Comment: This is what I get after debugging: No source available for "libstdc++-6!_ZNKSs7_M_dataEv() at 0x6fc5e26c"

Comment: Show us default constructor and destructor.

Comment: That is quite obviously not your code. Post a [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Added both constructor and destructor

Comment: You also need to show your copy-constructor, and the definition of `List`. Really, this would be simpler if you post the exact program that gives the problem

Comment: Almost definitely a Rule of Three problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Ok, just posted full code

Comment: Just added copy constructor and I still got the error

Comment: I don't see a copy constructor.  I see an assignment operator.  Having said that, your assignment operator is totally wrong.  The assignment operator is supposed to recreate the entire list, not just copy the pointer values.  The data from the sending list is to be recreated in the receiving list.  Just copying pointer values does nothing except causes your destructor to delete the same pointer value twice, causing all sorts of untold grief.  Please review the rule of 3, plus look at examples of how to properly do a `deep copy` as opposed to a `shallow copy`.

Comment: In addition, your destructor can be written in terms of removeMovie().  There is no need to write code that has already been written.  See this: `~Liat() { while (size > 0 ) removeMovie(head); }`  This assumes that removeMovie works correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added the copy constructor. What hapenning is that the debugger goes back to the copy constructor after returning, I don't know why.